# Making a span/div/p href-like or stopping href "executing" links

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the problem to "stop" href executing any links.
So my question is:

1) Is it possible replace href-elements that generate internal (#) links with any component, maybe `<p>`, `<div>` or `<span>` (or whatever could be working) that keep the same behaviour of `<a>` element (hovering, underlined etc) but not executing any link?

2) Alternative, a "trick" to avoiding href elements execute links?

1 or 2 without using jquery or any other js library possibly

Thanks Randomize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can prevent links from the default action - the recommended way is to have links work normally (in case JS is disabled or not available - think "mobile browsers"), and then override the default action with JS.

Unfortunately, due to cross-browser incompatibilities, there are three ways to do this ("traditional","W3C" and "IE") and you need all of them: `stopPropagation()`, `cancelBubble` and `return false`. See a complete example at QuirksMode: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html#link9

(Incidentally most JS frameworks abstract this away, so in jQuery you'd do this:

```
$('a').click(function(event){
    // do something on click here
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

This does the same thing as the QuirksMode example, but is a easier-to-read example.)

Answer (score 1):

You can either add an `onclick` attribute to specific `<a>` elements:

```
 <a href="whatever" onclick="return false"></a>
```

Or modify the `href` like this:

```
 <a href="javascript:"></a>
```

To make them look like links, without redirecting the browser.

---

If instead, you already have a bunch of links with `href`s, and you simply wish to make them all non-redirecting, then the following jQuery will do this to all links on the page:

```
$(function () {
    $('a').click(false);
});
```

Although nice and short, the above only works with jQuery-1.4.3+. If you are using an older version, then you can use the expanded form:

```
$(function () {
    $('a').click(function () { return false; });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. Is <a href="javascript:"></a> portable? (at least firefox 4, Explorer 7/8)

Answer (score 1):

There are all sorts of tricks that can be employed to do this kind of thing, but what you need to be careful of is modifying the behaviour from that which the users have come to expect from a browser.
For example , it would be possible to  swap the meaning of 'OK' & 'Cancel' buttons, but this would just confuse the user. (An extreme example, I know, but you get the idea)

If you could supply some more information about why you are trying to do this, there may be a better way of approaching things.

Answer (score 0):

TO disable the link via js add onclick="this.href='javascript:void(0)';" like so:

```
<a href="#" onclick="this.href='javascript:void(0)';">link text</a>
```

You can use a similar tactic to make other elements work link links:

```
<div onclick="this.href='http://www.mysite.com';"></div>
```

Comment: thanks your first solution works fine on firefox 4.0. At the moment I can't try on Explorer 7/8 but as far as you know, is it portable?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, I've used it before and don't remember having a problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

This is working in IE, chrome and firefox:

```
<a href="javascript:functionX();">text link</a>
```

In the function return void(0):

```
function functionX() {
...
return void(0);
}
```